# how do I return model parent values when I make a query from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

So I have a model called Image that belongs_to :user. Each user has a first and last name.

I have a flash app that I am returning a json object back to of Images.

the service I will be calling on the Images controller would look something like this

```
def getimages
    @images = Image.all
    render :json => @images

  end
```

My json would look something like this

```
[{"image":{"created_at":"2011-01-22T19:04:30Z","img_path":"assets/img/bowl_93847566_3_0.png","updated_at":"2011-01-22T19:04:30Z","id":9,"user_id":3}}]
```

what I would like to do is also include the users first and last name with in the image object that gets passed back.

once I have an image object I am able to do something like `image.user.first_name` but I am not clear how I would return something like an array of image objects and include the user along with it.

what would be great is if I could get my array of images to look like the following.

```
[{"image":{"created_at":"2011-01-22T19:04:30Z","img_path":"assets/img/bowl_93847566_3_0.png","updated_at":"2011-01-22T19:04:30Z","id":9,"user_id":3, "first_name":"Matthew", "last_name":"Wallace"}}]
```

I am thinking this may include adding some kind of model method or somthing that I am not familiar with.

What would be the best practice for achieving this?

Comment: why don't you create your own js.erb view with whatever you want inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
render :json => @images.to_json(:include => :users)
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json (and http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_json shows it works on Arrays). Finally, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render describes using `to_json` in a json render as optional and not required, which implies it should cause no harm (I couldn't see another way to pass the required options in).

Perhaps cleaner json:

```
render :json => @images.to_json(:include => { :user => { :only => [:first_name, :last_name] } })
```

Comment: this worked perfect ... the only change I made was I needed to use the singular version of :user and not :users

Comment: and let me be more clear. I used the final example you posted where I only include the first and last name rows.

Comment: I changed it to the singular, but the examples I read had it pluralised

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer provided by @apneadiving, you can also override the Image's `to_json` method and return a string containing whatever JSON you need.